# Using table name in the methods for displaying mysqli table data

Tags: php, mysqli

To display the mysqli data to the webpage I use a single function in display.php file which is:

```
public function tabledata($table){

    $data = array();
    $query  =  "SELECT * FROM `$table` WHERE `isdeleted`='0' and `status`='1' ORDER BY `displayorder` ";
    $result  =  $this->mysqli->query($query) or $this->checkerror($query);

    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        $data[]= $row;
    }
    return $data;
}
```

and to call it in the view I simply pass the name of table in the function:

```
 $technologypartner    = $display->tabledata("partner");
```

**or like**

```
$problemsolutionblock = $display->tabledata("problemsolution");
```

Is this approach is wrong? I am new to PHP and want to know if there are any issue regarding the use of table name in my PHP code where I have to display the html?

Comment: This is possible from a technical point of view, but rarely a good idea. It is not robust and hard to read as code. Why not use two separate queries? That also allows to modify the data model in future...

Comment: this is possible as per your code. But how do you plan to handle issues with columns? for example, what if the table does not have the same columns, you will get errors. You can alternatively pass additional parameters as columns. An array would help. Also i would strongly advise you add prepared statements here.

Comment: thanks i do use seperate queries when i have to fetch specific coloumns , i use this function only where i have to fetch all the table data records and some coloumns in my table are always same like deleted , status, or display order

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can fetch data from `mysql` table regarding of the table name you passed by doing that.

below is my test process:

[image]

but if want to display the table, since column names are different, you should probably fetch the column names as well, something like this.

```
SELECT
   COLUMN_NAME 
FROM
   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE
   TABLE_SCHEMA = '$table'
```